# SQL Database, repeated tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

On moving a site to localhost I noticed there are 150 tables? On further investigation it appears that many of the tables are repeated.

For example:

```
siwp206985_wp_wfHoover --> utf8_general_ci
siwp718377_wp_wfHoover --> utf8_general_ci
wp5684_wfHoover --> utf8_general_ci
```

This example all have the same collation. However there are different tables with different collations?

```
siwp206985_wp_wfLeechers --> latin1_swedish_ci
siwp665233_wp_wfLeechers --> latin1_swedish_ci
siwp718377_wp_wfLeechers --> latin1_swedish_ci
siwp825460_wp_wfLeechers --> latin1_swedish_ci
```

Again, same table, different versions?

There are also some utf8mb4_unicode_ci collations.

So clearly, in some instances, wp_wfLeechers being one, there are four versions of the same table. This seems excessive, common sense suggests I should only have one of each, the latest one?

Is there something odd going on here, or is this common place and I shouldn't worry?

Comment: Definitely something odd going on. Does it only happen with the WordFence tables? (the ones with the wf prefix)

Comment: No, every table is duplicated at least once, but some are duplicated four times?